# Como puedo comprobar que todos los input de misma clase tengan valor de 0

Tags: html, jquery

Necesito evaluar si todos los input con la clase "hour" tengan el valor de 0, pensé en hacerlo con each pero no me funciona.

```
if ($('.productTextInput').filter(function() {
}).length === 0) {
    console.log("Todos en 0");
}
else {
    console.log("algunos diferentes de 0")
}
```

Comment: ¿Que tipo de input son??

Comment: <input type="text" class="hour">

Answer (score 2):

Con `each` puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
var bandera = false;
$(".hour").each(function(){
    if ( $(this).val() !== '0' )
     bandera = true;
});
if (bandera)
   alert("Hay datos distintos");
else
   alert("Son ceros");
```

Lo único que debes definir correctamente es tu selector para que el evento haga el match correcto de los elementos que deseas.

```js
$(".send").click(function(){
    var bandera = false;
    $(".hour").each(function(){
        if ( $(this).val() !== '0' )
         bandera = true;
    });
    if (bandera)
       alert("Hay datos distintos");
    else
       alert("Son ceros");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="0" class="hour">
<input type="text" value="0" class="hour">
<input type="text" value="0" class="hour">
<input type="text" value="0" class="hour">
<input type="text" value="0" class="hour">
<input type="button" value="ver" class="send">
```

**Nota**: Cambia los valores de los inputs para ver los resultados

Answer (score 0):

Puedes comprobar tambien con este ejemplo, usando un filtro sobre tu arreglo de elementos inputs puedes verificar cuando alguno de ellos tenga un valor diferente de 0.

```js
$('#check').on('click', function(){
 //Obtienes todos los campos cuyo valor sea diferente a 0
 var elements = $('.hour').filter(function(index,item){
   return parseInt(item.value) !== 0;
 });
        //Puede ser de esta manera tambien un poco mas simplificada
        //var elements = $('.hour').filter((index,item) => parseInt(item.value) !== 0);

 //Si hay elementos que tienen valores diferentes a 0...
 if(elements.length > 0){
  alert('Hay elementos diferentes de 0');
 } else {
  alert('No Hay elementos diferentes de 0');
 }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="hour" value="1"/>
<input type="text" class="hour" value="0"/>
<input type="text" class="hour" value="0"/>
<input type="text" class="hour" value="0"/>
<input type="text" class="hour" value="0"/>
<input type="text" class="hour" value="0"/>
<input type="button" value="Comprobar" id="check" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te estaría faltando la condición del filtro, por cada elemento se retorna el elemento si y sólo si el valor no es 0 y así el conjunto final contendrá los que no son 0. algo así:

```js
$("#dale").click(function() {
  if (
    $('.productTextInput').filter(function(idx, el) {
      return 0 !== parseInt($(el).val())
    }).length === 0
  ) {
    console.log("Todos en 0");
  } else {
    console.log("algunos diferentes de 0")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="0" class="productTextInput">
<input type="text" value="0" class="productTextInput">
<input type="text" value="0" class="productTextInput">
<input type="text" value="0" class="productTextInput">
<input type="text" value="0" class="productTextInput">
<button id="dale">verificar</button>
```